# Why my inline functions have linking error?

Tags: c++, function, class, inline-functions

I am learning C++ and currently testing inline functions. If I run my code now I will have linking error, but if I change
`inline void Test::print40()`
to
`void Test::print40()`
everything would be fine. Could you explain to me why I have an error and how to use inline function in this case.

```
// main.cpp file
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test obj1;
    obj1.print40();
}
```

```
// Test.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

inline void Test::print40()
{
    std::cout << "40";
}
```

```
// Test.h file
#pragma once

class Test
{
public:
    void print40();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline function definition shall be in each compilation unit where it is ODR used.

On the other hand in your project the compilation unit main does not know that the function is an inline function. So it can not find its definition.

Move this definition from `Test.cpp`

```
#pragma once

class Test
{
public:
    void print40();
};

inline void Test::print40()
{
    std::cout << "40";
}
```

to the header `Test.h`.

The module `Test.cpp` is redundant.

As the function is very simple and short then it could be defined in the class definition as for example

```
class Test
{
public:
    void print40()
    {
        std::cout << "40";
    }
};
```

In this case it will be an inline function by default.

Comment: ничё не понял, если я в определении класса перед void print40(); допишу inline ничего не поменяется

Comment: @Denis As I said the definition of an inline function shall be in each compilation module.  If you will place the inline specifier in the function declaration inside the class definition nothing will be changed. The definition of the function is not available in main.cpp. So move the definition of the function in the header,

Comment: @Denis ODR - one definition rule.

Comment: как расшифровуется ODR?

Comment: @Denis In this forum you have to write comments in English.

Comment: получается что встраиваемые функции должны находиться полностью только в заголовочных файлах? (OK in English)

Comment: @Denis  The definition of an inline function shall be in each compilation unit where it is called. It is not necessary that the definition shall be only in a header. Nevertheless it is  more suitable to place the definition in a header because there will no duplicates of the code.

Comment: I understand this, thanks for explanation, but is it a good practice to use an inline functions for settter, getter and other small functions, and if so what is better to to declare inline function in the class or after the class definition in the same header file?

Comment: @Denis There is no problem to declare a short function either getter or setter as an inline function.  It is better to declare them inline in the class definition.